# Problem in highlighting the empty lines using the react-diff-viewer

Tags: reactjs

Have written a code to show the difference between 2 java files using DiffViewer library in react. But unable to highlight the empty lines in the modified file ie. the newValue. Anyone have the solution? Below is the code

```
    <DiffViewer
        oldValue={selectedsrcFileContent}
        newValue={selecteddestFileContent}
        splitView={true}
        hideLineNumbers={false}
        disableWordDiff={true}
        compareMethod={DiffMethod.TRIMMED_LINES}
        renderContent={(
          source,
          diffType,
          diff,
          isHighlighted,
        ) => (
          <pre className={`diff-line ${isHighlighted ? "highlight" : ""}`}>
            {diffType === "deleted" ? (
              <span className="diff-deleted">{source}</span>
            ) : diffType === "added" ? (
              <span className="diff-added">{diff}</span>
            ) : (
              <span>{source}</span>
            )}
          </pre>
        )}
      />
```

I want to Highlight the deleted lines in the modified file.